# Swiftui navigation to notification view and back to detail view of a list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

**Expected use case**
Tab B -> list View -> Detail View

On tapping notification
Tab B -> list view -> Detail view -> Notification detail view

navigating back

Tab B -> list view -> Detail View

**but it working like below**

Tab B -> list View -> Detail View

On tapping notification
Tab B -> list view -> Detail view -> Notification detail view

navigating back

Tab B -> list view

```
struct ContentView: View {
     let todoPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("Detail"))

       @State var show: Bool = false
       @State var navigationTitle: String = "First"

       var body: some View {
           NavigationView {
               VStack {
                      NavigationLink(destination: Detail(), isActive: self.$show) { Text("")}.hidden()
                      // HiddenNavigationLink(destination: Detail(), isActive: self.$show)

                       TabView() {
                           FirtstView(navigationTitle: self.$navigationTitle)
                           .tabItem {
                               Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                               Text("First")
                           }.tag(0)
                               
                           ListView(navigationTitle: self.$navigationTitle)
                          // ListView()
                           .tabItem {
                               Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                               Text("Second")
                           }.tag(1)
                               
                   }

               }
           .navigationBarTitle(navigationTitle)
           }
           .onReceive(todoPublisher) {notification in
               self.show = true
           }
         
       }
}
```

Here is the list view code

```
struct ListView: View {
    @Binding var navigationTitle: String
    var body: some View {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<5) {data in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                                    Text("Text for row \(data)")
                            }
                        }
                }
        .onAppear() {
        self.navigationTitle = "Second"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code directly in the question, don't post links to GitHub.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

A `NavigationLink` always has a *parent*, ie. a view that *contains* the NavigationLink. When you tap on the *back arrow* it will pop the NavigationLink and navigates back to this parent view.

In your case you're presenting a hidden NavigationLink from the `ContentView`. Which means that the `ContentView` becomes a *parent* of the `NavigationLink`.

If you want the NavigationLink's back arrow to navigate to the `DetailView` instead, you need to initiate the NavigationLink from the `DetailView`.

Which means that your hidden NavigationLink needs to be presented from a `DetailView`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ...
        NavigationLink(destination: Detail(), isActive: self.$show) { 
            EmptyView() 
        }.hidden()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a good point, but notification may arrive any time on any screen. on tapping notification it has to navigate to notification detail view and navigating back it has to show the previous view from where it navigated.

Comment: @kirang39 Then what I recommend you to do is to add a *sheet* to the ContentView - this way you don't need to change handling the notifications. Otherwise you may need to add a NavigationLink and notifications handling for every view.